# Delete all files in a directory using Chef

Tags: chef-infra

Attempting to delete a non-empty folder:

```
directory "C:\tempdirectory" do
 action :delete
end
```

... in Chef I receive:

```
Errno::ENOTEMPTY
Directory not empty
```

Is there a quick way to delete all files in the directory?

Or an argument or flag to allow me to delete non-empty directories?

Comment: I assume you're using a simple `:delete` action on a standard directory resource block?

Comment: Yes, sorry editing to add code

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If I recall correctly, setting the `recursive true` attribute will force remove non-empty directories.

[The docs for the `directory` LWRP](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html#examples) don't describe this behavior, but they do provide this usage example:

```
directory "/tmp/something" do
  recursive true
  action :delete
end
```

The docs have since been amended to cryptically say:

> `recursive`
> Ruby Types: TrueClass, FalseClass
>
> Create or delete parent directories recursively. For the owner, group, and mode properties, the value of this attribute applies only to the leaf directory.
> Default value: `false`.

They still stop short of saying "`recursive true` is required to delete non-empty directories. Without this setting, attempting to delete a non-empty directory will fail with the message: `Errno::ENOTEMPTY Directory not empty`".

Comment: Thanks, works great. Didn't see any note about it in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, it's not mentioned in there at all.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the `recursive true` option. This option will remove all the directories.